# Webpack watch build causes page to go blank

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to figure out why the build process of Webpack results in a blank page. Here is the scenario.

On the first generation of my dist folder everything works fine. The page reloads and I see my app. If I then make a change to a file Webpack build runs again but this time it results in a blank screen.

If I then kill my app and restart the app loads the content from the dist folder fine.. But then Webpack starts building again (without any changes on my part). When it completes the page reloads and the content is blank? I'm pretty sure this is related to a bad setting in webpack.config.js. Just not sure what it is.

Some context on what I'm doing. I'm basically trying to take an [Electron/Angular](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron). bootstrap project and put in another angular app I purchased. So the webpack.config.js I'm using was created for a different angular app which is where I think something is wrong.

This is more or less the [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/blob/master/webpack.config.js) I'm working with.

Here is my project structure in case that helps
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w6o0.png)

Anyone have any suggestions on where to look to fix this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I've got a very similar problem, except the part where it builds again on its own.  When I save a change, a new bundle is generated by watch, but the page goes blank.  Stopping and starting webpack makes the page work again.